# Swift single argument with autoclosure without braces at all

Tags: swift, functional-programming, closures

I would like to achieve Haskell `elem` function with Apple Swift language.

This looks like not very hard to implement:

```
func elem<T: Equatable>(item: T) -> [T] -> Bool {
    return { arr in find(arr, item) != nil }
}

elem(2)([1,2,3])
```

But I wanna to skip braces for arguments. It is possible for last(or single) argument of closure type:

```
func elem<T: Equatable>(item: ()->T) -> (()->[T]) -> Bool {
    return { (arr: ()->[T]) in find(arr(), item()) != nil }
}

elem{2}{[1,2,3]}
```

But here we have an error:

```
Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ':'
```

This error is a real problem, which looks like compiler imperfection. But we need to go deeper to avoid brackets `{}`, it can be achieved with `@autoclosure`:

```
func elem<T: Equatable>(item: @autoclosure ()->T) -> (@autoclosure ()->[T]) -> Bool {
    return { (arr: @autoclosure ()->[T]) in find(arr(), item()) != nil }
}

elem 2 [1,2,3]
```

And we have the same error.

I think Swift compiler should not give me this errors. Are there any other ways to avoid braces and brackets?

Comment: I don't think you can just arbitrarily remove braces. Like it or not Swift's syntax imposes the need for a lot of parens to force application.

Comment: SO is not the right forum for this kind of question (syntax change proposal). You better off posting this question on Apple's Swift forum and engage Chris Lattner or SevenTenEleven